# Galois actions on cohomology rings of algebraic varieties

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

Let $k$ be an arithmetic field. Let $G_k$ be its absolute Galois group.

$G_k$ is often studied via its linear action on cohomology (etale, crystalline, ...) "groups" of algebraic varieties over $k$.

The cohomology of a variety, however, also has a ring structure. One can, therefore, ask how $G_k$ acts on the entire cohomology ring of a variety via ring automorphisms.

Are such ring actions meaningful and useful? Could you point to examples if so?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  The cohomology ring of an Abelian variety is a free exterior algebra on the  degree $1$ cohomology.  Thus, the group of automorphisms of the degree $1$ cohomology equals the group of automorphism of the cohomology ring.

Comment: @JasonStarr, Thank you for this great class of examples. Are there also examples of actions that "genuinely" exploit the ring structure, and thereby tell us something about $G_k$ that may not be inferred from its actions on the individual cohomology groups in those cases?